# How to select only first row from repeating values in columns of dataframe in apache-spark?

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark-sql

Consider I do have the `dataframe` containing following data,

```
val seq = Seq((1, "John"), (1, "John"), (2, "Michael"), (3, "Sham"),(4, "Dan"), (2, "Michael"), (4, "Dan"))

val rdd = sc.parallelize(seq)

val df = rdd.toDF("id","name")
```

I want `output` as :

> 1, "John"
>
> 2, "Michael"
>
> 3, "Sham"
>
> 4, "Dan"

How can I `select` only `row` from the `dataset` where repeatation is allowed on the both id and name `column`.

Comment: you mean to say you want output with only repeated values ..? in your case "Sham" should not be in the output. is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dropDuplicates() on dataframe/dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for distinct values from the Data Frame.

```
df.distinct.orderBy("id").show();
```

You can drop the orderBy if don't want the ordering of results. 

`+---+-------+
| id|   name|
+---+-------+
|  1|   John|
|  2|Michael|
|  3|   Sham|
|  4|    Dan|
+---+-------+`